# Is it possible with CallKit Framework to make, answer and end telephonic call or is it used for VOIP call only?

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, core-telephony, callkit

I want to perform the action on telephonic calls with the help of CallKit, but as per Apple documentation, it can be used to make VOIP calls only, is there any way through which I can make outgoing calls, end the current call and answer incoming telephone calls with the help of CallKit.

I am using private framework (TelephonyUtilities), trying to do the above mentioned activities.

```
NSBundle *bundlePath = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework"];
 if ([bundlePath load]) {   
    Class TUCallCenter = NSClassFromString(@"TUCallCenter");
    id tuCallCenter = [TUCallCenter sharedInstance];
}
```

But none of TUCallCenter methods allow me to initiate telephony call from my app. Although there are defined methods available.
Some of which are :

```
- (id)_dial:(id)arg1 callID:(int)arg2 service:(int)arg3 sourceIdentifier:(id)arg4 dialType:(int)arg5 uniqueProxyIdentifier:(id)arg6;
- (id)_dialWithRequest:(id)arg1 completion:(id /* block */)arg2;
- (id)callWithCallUUID:(id)arg1;
- (id)callWithStatus:(int)arg1;
- (id)callWithUniqueProxyIdentifier:(id)arg1;
- (id)callsWithStatus:(int)arg1;
- (id)dial:(id)arg1 callID:(int)arg2 service:(int)arg3;
- (id)dial:(id)arg1 callID:(int)arg2 service:(int)arg3 sourceIdentifier:(id)arg4 uniqueProxyIdentifier:(id)arg5;
- (id)dial:(id)arg1 service:(int)arg2;
- (id)dialEmergency:(id)arg1;
- (id)dialEmergency:(id)arg1 sourceIdentifier:(id)arg2;
- (id)dialWithRequest:(id)arg1;
- (void)dialWithRequest:(id)arg1 completion:(id /* block */)arg2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CallKit**

Display the system-calling UI for your app's VoIP services, and coordinate your calling services with other apps and the system.

---

**Overview**

CallKit lets you integrate your calling services with other call-related apps on the system. CallKit provides the calling interface, and you handle the back-end communication with your VoIP service. For incoming and outgoing calls, CallKit displays the same interfaces as the Phone app, giving your app a more native look and feel. And CallKit responds appropriately to system-level behaviors such as Do Not Disturb.

In addition to handling calls, you can provide a Call Directory app extension to provide caller ID information and a list of blocked numbers associated with your service.

**Receiving an Incoming Call**

Receiving an incoming call method straight forward leads to PushKit silent notification which used in VOIP apps.

```
// MARK: PKPushRegistryDelegate
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
    // report new incoming call
}
```

So, there is no chance of using CallKit apart from VOIP apps.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Hope this helps to understand scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Not without a jailbreak (**EDIT**: Or without using a private framework, for a privately released app) I'm afraid.

CallKit is meant to make your VoIP calls appear on the Phone app, like these ones here. [image: An example of CallKit] CallKit can also make a call of your VoIP app appear just like a stock Voice Call to the user.

What you're looking for, requires a private framework instead, but in that case you're either coding for a jailbroken release, or a private release for your client. To do so, you need to look into TelephonyUtilities.framework probably. Check it out [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework). TUCall seems to be a call object through which you can get the details or end it, while [TUCallCenter](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TUCallCenter.h) has an incomingCalls method. So this can indeed work, just in a private release, not an App Store app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Its an enterprise application, so I can use private frameworks, but not jailbroken devices, I will try with TelephonyUtilities.framework

Comment: @JasmeetSingh Yes, private frameworks are allowed for enterprise applications. If you get into TelephonyUtilities' flow, you can probably do all of the above. If it's your first time using a private framework, I would recommend you to check the README of the same [git repo](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/README.md), as it explains how to import it and use it!

Comment: I am able to access the private framework, but when I try to make call through TUCallCenter it does not work, I have used all the methods available for dial, Don't know what I am missing. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @JasmeetSingh Well I've been a jailbreak and private framework developer since I began iOS development in 2011, so usually when the behaviour isn't what you expect, usually you're missing some piece. For example, how did you create TUCallCenter? With alloc - init? Because generally with private frameworks, there's some generic way to invoke them. For example, does another class have a CallCenter property? Is there a class method anywhere? Such as + (id) sharedManager, through which you build your way to TUCallCenter? As usually, alloc init won't work in private frameworks…

Comment: I have edited the question, where I have mentioned how I have implemented the TUCallCenter, and its instance has been created, but I am unable to make telephony call. Can you help me in this.

Comment: @JasmeetSingh Definetely, but as I said above an instance alone in a private framework doesn't make much sense. Let me give you an example. To get the image from the Switcher (I've done this yesterday), I didn't get directly to the Screenshot class. I passed through 6 instances of classes. What you need to to is look for ***other*** classes in TelephonyUtilities.framework, where there's a callCenter property or method. If that class can be initiated directly (again try), then you've found it. If not, look for methods returning this class's instance in again, other classes.

Comment: @JasmeetSingh This is pretty much reverse engineering the framework. You know the destination (TUCallCenter), but as you see, an instance of TUCallCenter doesn't mean much, it probably needs some properties set, or ivars and the usual way to do this, is to reach your instance from other classes as I've said above. I know it can be frustrating, but you can't imagine the satisfaction when you've solved the puzzle!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147910/discussion-between-jasmeet-singh-and-isklikas).